# How to fill combo box from "horizontal" range of cells?

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

Let's say I have a row of cells, which have the following values:

```
B2: "banana"
C2: "orange"
D2: "apple"
```

I take this range and turn it into a 2-dimensional array. My main code is in a Word document:

```
dim MySheet as Excel.Worksheet
dim arr as variant
Set MySheet = Excel.Sheets(1)
arr = MySheet.Range(MySheet.Cells(2, 2), MySheet.Cells(2, 4))
```

I have a combobox `CbbFruits` and I don't want to add the items one by one, so I use the `.list` method:

```
CbbFruits.List = arr
```

Only the "banana" entry is added. As I understand for this method to work the array and therefore the range of cells has to be positioned vertically.

I don't want to reshuffle my cells. Is there a method to switch axes of an array?

Comment: Consider using `MySheet.Cells(2, 2).Resize(1,2)` which is cleaner because you control the size of the table of cells, instead of `MySheet.Range(MySheet.Cells(2, 2), MySheet.Cells(2, 4))`. Better yet `MySheet.Range("B2").Resize(1,2)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem with creating an array from an Excel range is that the values are represented horizontally (remember, it's a 2D array). You need to [transpose](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheetfunction.transpose) the array to have the values represented vertically. The easiest way to do that in Word-VBA is to use your already existing `Excel.Application` object.

Here's a full example:

```
Private Sub Test()
    Dim oExcel As New Excel.Application
    Dim oWb As Excel.Workbook: Set oWb = oExcel.Workbooks.Open(filePath)

    Dim MySheet As Excel.Worksheet
    Set MySheet = oWb.Worksheets(1)
    Dim arr As Variant
    arr = MySheet.Range(MySheet.Cells(2, 2), MySheet.Cells(2, 4))

    CbbFruits.List = oExcel.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(arr)

    oWb.Close SaveChanges:=False
    oExcel.Quit
End Sub
```